# ES6 equivalent of require('module').function()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, require, javascript-import

Here is my code

```
var foobar  = require('module').foobar()
foobar.useOne()
foobar.useTwo()
```

I am looking for the ES6 equivalent of the first line (with `import ... as ... from`) so that i can still do `foobar.useOne()`, `foobar.useTwo()` etc
If there is one..

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_importing-exporting-details

Comment: are you usign commonjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your module exposes a factory method, so you need an intermediate variable to store the foobar instance.

```
import { foobar as Foobar } from 'module';
const foobar = Foobar();
foobar.useOne();
foobar.useTwo();
```